# serialize an array to send to php in hyperlink

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, submit, serialization

I have this:

```
var postData = {};
                    $('#items tr').not(':first').each(function(index, value) {
                        var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = index;
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[supp_short_code]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.supp_short_code').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[project_ref]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.project_ref').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[om_part_no]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.om_part_no').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[description]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[quantity_input]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity_input').val();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_of_items]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text();
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_total_td]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_total_td').text();
                    });
```

What would be my next step to send this to PHP, i dont want to use Ajax because i need to go the PHP page and view the received results. The idea is to take values from a table, when the user presses "Preview" it will take these values and take them to a PHP page which i will have have set up an Invoice style page which i will populate with the above values?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to run into several problems here, for starters you're running a terribly inefficient DOM traversal loop, but more so you're going to blow the GET request length limit in older browsers.

Comment: fair enough, how could i send these via POST then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont want to use Ajax because i need
>   to go the PHP page and view the
>   received results

The logic doesnt seem too clear here- at present it seems you use JS to query your DB based on some criteria, assign the results to arrays then push the results to a PHP page to output them?

Instead of sending the resultset via GET/POST to the page, why dont you send ONLY whatever variables you use to construct your initial criteria, then on the PHP preview page, use PHP to query the DB, get the results and show them.

You should always try to refrain from sending a complete resultset via GET/POST to another page, you should aim to only send operators which help you either get or create the resultset.

Comment: That makes sense. I have two buttons below the "order table" one is a "preview button" and one is a "submit" button. So what i could do is get people to press submit so its inserts the order into a db, then have the "preview" button as regular hyperlink sending the "order_id" via GET. Then pull back the order via the "order_id" from the db for the "preview" part...thanks!

Comment: No problem, sometimes its easy- especially when in the midst of development- to not always recognise a more efficient/practical approach, I know it happens to me!

Answer (score 1):

**About sending the values by POST :**
Build a string with a delimiter that seperates values, and insert the string into a hidden field. Change the form tag to use `method="post"`. When you send the form you will have a php variable something like : `$_POST['hiddenFieldName']` with the string you built. Now you will have to separate the string like you built it to retrieve the values.

**An important note about security :** 
It seems like this is some kind of shopping cart- I'm guessing this by the keys that hint about the price. If this is so, and users can order from this site, you are prone to some big security issues via [Parameter Tampering](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering).
In order to avoid this, just send an array (or string, like i explained), with id's and quantities of the chosen items. On the page where you view the items, retrieve there prices from the DB again, and recalculate the total. All calculations should be done on the server side.